# Empty text box, need to warn

Tags: javascript, php

I need to warn people when they don't fill out a form, for example there are 2 text boxes, 1. the Title, 2. Description and when users forget to put a title they will see a warning.

I've tried something, but it only works when I don't fill out a image link and not the title:

javascript

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form"]["title"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Title not filled in.");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["form"]["pic"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("IMAGE link is missing.");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

php

ADD NEW POST

```
<?php
// POST.PHP POSTING NEW CONTENT
include 'config.php';


                // values from form
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                            $id=$_POST['id'];
                            $title=$_POST['title'];
                            $pic=$_POST['pic'];
                            $youtube=$_POST['youtube'];
                            $cat=$_POST['cat'];


                            // insert data to mysql

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, title, pic, youtube, cat)VALUES('$id', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat')";
                            $result=mysql_query($sql);
                            }
                            // succes added
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $id=$_POST['id'];
                            echo "Yeah, buddy! Your content is added.";
                            }


                            // end of post script ^^
?> 


<?php
    echo '<b>Post your content</b><br />
        <a href="/post.php?pic">Add IMG from URL</a> | <a href="/post.php?addyt">Add Youtube video</a>';
    ?>

    <?php

            //POST IMAGE PAGE
            if(isset($_GET['pic'])) { 
            ?>
```

html

```
<form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
title: <input name="title" type="text" id="title"><br />
```

Add url of image;
    
     ';

```
 $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category`");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ 
echo '
       <option value="'.$row["nameID"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option> ';
        } 
    ?>


 </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: 2 function with same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to add something html5 required is also excellent

```
<input type="text" required />
```

NOTE I JUST GOT KNOW not on all browsers :)

YOU accepted this answer but you still need javascript to ensure as it dont work on all browsers

Comment: thats y i wrote browser i used thankx for telling :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second function overrides the first function. Either combine them or make it 2 functions.

```
function validateForm() {
{
var x=document.forms["form"]["title"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Title not filled in.");
  return false;
  }
}
var x=document.forms["form"]["pic"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("IMAGE link is missing.");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Needed to add { } between te code, after validateForm(), but I've one more question, I have added `{
var x=document.forms["form"]["youtube"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Youtube link is missing.");
  return false;
  }
}`  

But he doesn't give the error


`<form name="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    title: <input name="title" type="text" id="title"><br />
     
   Add url of youtube;<br />
    <input type="text" name="youtube" id="youtube"/><br />`

Comment: @Hadscape If you have a new question, ask it.